# How do I determine a USB memory stick's serial number in Cygwin?

Tags: usb, cygwin, serial

I already know that within windows, you can get a USB memory drive's Volume Serial Number by doing `dir <drive_letter>:`, where `<drive_letter>` is the drive letter of the USB drive. I also did some searching and found that Linux has a command called lsusb that will also give you the Volume Serial Number.

Is there a corresponding command in Cygwin?  I can't find lsusb in any of the setup files (libusb didn't have it).

I have a script that runs and copies files to a particular USB memory stick every day.  The problem is that I can't guarantee it will be the only USB memory stick plugged into my computer at any given time, and Windows assigns drive letters to USB memory sticks arbitrarily.  Matching the volume serial number will allow me to be sure I am writing to the correct USB drive.

Comment: if Cygwin truly doesnt have lsusb, then you can always download the source and compile it

Comment: "within windows..." - There's the `vol` command as well.

Comment: @Karan: Right, but I am running a perl script from within cygwin, so I need a method to access the serial number from there.

Comment: I know, I was just adding to your comment about `dir`. I'm sure there must be some way to get the required info via Perl as well.

Comment: I'm using `getVolInfo` from the cygwin package [csih](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53742791/display-volume-label-using-cygwin).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use **diskpart**. This is included in most recent versions of MS Windows, to the best of my knowledge. I am using *Windows 7 Starter Edition* (so I have very little in the way of "expert technical tools" such as one assumes would be provided with a "server" or "professional" edition of Windows). Nonetheless, I have **diskpart**.

Note that you may need to grapple with **UAC** (User Access Control) in order to run diskpart at all, even just to get information about disks or partitions (and I consider elaboration about UAC from perl to be beyond the scope of the question ;-). And note that diskpart is basically an interactive tool, and although the documentation describes using scripts to operate it, I have not yet tried that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some information from /proc/registry that might be useful e.g. the last line in the following is for a USB device:

```
$ more /proc/registry/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/partmgr/Enum/*
::::::::::::::
/proc/registry/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/partmgr/Enum/0
::::::::::::::
Root\LEGACY_PARTMGR\0000
::::::::::::::
/proc/registry/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/partmgr/Enum/1
::::::::::::::
IDE\DiskWDC_WD2500BEVS-22UST0___________________01.01A01\4&1375d492&0&0.0.0
::::::::::::::
/proc/registry/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/partmgr/Enum/2
::::::::::::::
USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_Brother&Prod_MFC-5860CN&Rev_1.00\8&6604242&0&BROL6F685804&0
::::::::::::::
/proc/registry/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/partmgr/Enum/3
::::::::::::::
uuid:73656761-7465-7375-636b-0090a9b61377\UMB\3&1e7e4b7a&0&uuid:73656761-7465-7375-636b-0090a9b61377
::::::::::::::
/proc/registry/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/partmgr/Enum/4
::::::::::::::
SD\VID_27&OID_5048&PID_SD04G&REV_3.0\5&fda7c2c&0&0
::::::::::::::
/proc/registry/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/partmgr/Enum/5
::::::::::::::
USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_Multi&Prod_Flash_Reader&Rev_1.00\9&4b089fb&0&058F0O1111B1&0
```